# Using Gson in Android

Tags: android, gson, httpclient

I am using google-gson to get data from one rest web service but LogCat displays me android.os.NetWorkOnMainThreadException. For the connection to the web service I am using httpclientandroidlib package from https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/.

My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.HttpEntity;
import ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.HttpResponse;
import ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.HttpStatus;
import ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.client.methods.HttpGet;
import ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/SightsWebService/sights/getFun";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        ListKozanisPlaces sightsList = gson.fromJson(reader, ListKozanisPlaces.class);


        for ( int counter = 0; counter < sightsList.getList().size(); counter++ )
            Toast.makeText(this, sightsList.getList().get( counter ).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) 
    {    
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {      
           HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
              Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                  "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
           return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
           getRequest.abort();
           Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }   
        return null;     
    }
}
```

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: And may also want to consider using Retrofit or Volley libraries since they simplify the need for AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies [android does not allow for networking operations on the "main" thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). You need to do these operations on an other thread. The simplest way to go about this is with an [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding). A quick google search should net you several tutorials on Asynctasks.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your network operations

For a demo sample, you can refer this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/04/androidosnetworkonmainthreadexception.html